# What's the activity called that asks customers to contribute ideas, picks the best idea and then rewards the contributor?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase common in use to describe this kind of activity?

Comment: Sounds like the classic Suggestion Box.

Answer (score 1):

See [Innovation competition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innovation_competition) at Wikipedia.

> An innovation competition is a method or process of the industrial process, product or business development. It is a form of social engineering, which focuses to the creation and elaboration of the best and sustainable ideas, coming from the best innovators.
>
> example - Encourage Adidas users to participate in an open innovation process, to inspire their creativity, and to increase the quality of the submissions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like customer feedback.

Though they usually don't give rewards for it. Well, some do if they make you fill in a questionnaire.

Answer (score 0):

the activity falls into a method or technique of **best practices**  [TFD](https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/best+practice)

> The most effective and/or most ethical actions a professional, company
>   or industry can take. For example, a company may be engaging in best
>   practices when it makes an extra effort to establish an ongoing
>   relationship with customers [*via such interactive poll*] to encourage repeat business. Many
>   professional organizations exist to promote best practices in their
>   respective industries.

In this case: What's good for the customer goose [feeling involved regardless a tangible or monetary reward] is good for the company gander.